# Retrofit error on GET request

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I am getting an unexpected error from retrofit during an HTTP GET request.  The request looks like this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("/videos/random/token")
void getRandomToken(String user_id, String word, String lang, String type, Callback<VideoMetadata> metadataCallback);
```

Here is the retrofit implementation:

```
public void getRandomToken(String user_id, String word, String lang, String type) {
    clerkService.getRandomToken(user_id, word, lang, type, new RetrofitCallback<VideoMetadata>() {

        @Override
        public void success(VideoMetadata messageObject, Response response) {
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                Utility.showDebugToast("Unexpected Response:\n" + response.getStatus());
            }
            Log.d("success", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            super.failure(error);
            Log.d("error", error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

On the first request, I get the following Retrofit error:

```
No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

And on following requests:

```
Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: GET and GET.
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: check your imports. You could be importing another `GET` annotation

Comment: also, don't you need the @Query annotation on the parameters?

Comment: Do I?  Can you provide an example using that annotation?

Comment: basically any example on the retrofit homepage.

Answer (score 0):

don't have the leading '/' in the @GET, when you do retrofit interprets it as an absolute and doesn't include the application name in the URL, I ran into that problem on my first implementation